# How can I push an already existing file on GitHub, but this time with a different name?

Tags: github

I created a project folder and push its content to GitHub
Now I decided to change files names ( from Structure to structure for example) Once I push again, the name of the file still the same on Github.
Any help would be appreciated.

Regards

Comment: Create a copy, push and delete the old one, what's the issue

Comment: the issue is that when I push to GitHub the file name still the same. And I don't ant to create a copy.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to rename a file, you can use
    `git mv oldfile newfile`

Otherwise, if you stage all the files, git wll detect that one file is deleted and the other is new. Note that some operating systems are not case sensitive for filenames (e.g. windows)

Comment: Do you mean that renaming via Terminal is not equivalent to renaming directly the file ? Note I am on mac. Actually, I have no problem with Git. It is GitHub that is not taking into consideration the name changes

Comment: No, it's not the same thing. If you rename the file using your OS, you have to stage the new file with `git add .` and then commit. If you just want to rename it, you use `git mv` which will both rename the file *and* stage the changes